# Ignoring white space in palindrome

Tags: c#, regex, string, palindrome

I am writing a program to check if a word is palindrome. The program itself works
but when I enter this specific line of text "too bad - i hid a boot" it will not pick it up
and ignore the white space and hyphen.

I looked at previous questions but I cant find a answer.

Is my `Regex.Replace` incorrect?

```
 string s, revs = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Word");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        string r = Regex.Replace(s , @"[^-\s]", "");

        for (int i = s.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            revs += s[i].ToString();
        }

        if (revs == s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entered string is palindrome \n String was {0} and reverse string was {1}", s, revs);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String entered was not palindrome.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: did you try debugging? What is the result after your Replace is applied?

Comment: It just picks up that line of text as not palindrome. seems to make no difference.

Comment: I am talking about the result with a breakpoint before the for loop.

Comment: Why use an always less readable regex over string.Replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contains two errors:

- This is the correct Regex condition `@"(\s|-)"` yours replaces everything but the characters you want to remove
- As jeffdot pointed out, you're replacing (incorrectly) but then testing against the original string

This considered, the correct code should be:

```
string s, revs = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Word");
        s = Console.ReadLine();
        string r = Regex.Replace(s , @"(\s|-)", "");

        for (int i = r.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            revs += r[i].ToString();
        }

        if (revs == r)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Entered string is palindrome \n String was {0} and reverse string was {1}", s, revs);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("String entered was not palindrome.");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Except for the first `WriteLine` in which you should decide what to print (since revs doesn't contain spaces and the hyphen anymore).

Or if you want to just use `String.Replace`, you can use it twice with:

```
s=s.Replace(' ','');
s=s.Replace('-','');
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. i see now where i went wrong and see how i should have referenced r.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of that `Regex.Replace` call to `string r` and you are never referencing it. This is why your comparison is failing.

To make that more clear: you are removing whitespace and referencing that product as `string r` but you are reversing and testing against `string s` only.

Saverio also points out that your regex isn't going to work (I didn't test that myself).

You have:

```
    string r = Regex.Replace(s , @"[^-\s]", "");

    for (int i = s.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        revs += s[i].ToString();
    }
```

Right there you should be iterating and reversing `r` instead of `s` --because `s` still has all its whitespace.

Further, as Saverio has said, why not just replace?

```
string r = s.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Reverse();
```

I haven't tried to compile that but as long as you are not using a very old version of the .NET framework that should work.  It may require that you are `using System.Linq` to use the `Reverse()` extension.

Comment: yes i see what you mean now but how would i reference string r?

Comment: While jeff is correct about you not referencing the modified string, also your regex is wrong, as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: Do you see where, after replacing whitespace into string r, you are then indexing string s?  I'll add some example in my answer but this should be relatively clear.